# JavaFX: работа с Bridj

Tags: java, javafx

Пытаюсь задать прогресс бар в панели задач для приложения

```
ITaskbarList3 list = null;
try {
    list = COMRuntime.newInstance(ITaskbarList3.class);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

но вылетает ошибка

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected COM error code : -2147417850
>       at org.bridj.cpp.com.COMRuntime.error(COMRuntime.java:197)
>       at org.bridj.cpp.com.COMRuntime$1.initialValue(COMRuntime.java:231)
>       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.setInitialValue(ThreadLocal.java:180)
>       at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:170)
>       at org.bridj.cpp.com.COMRuntime.initialize(COMRuntime.java:254)
>       at org.bridj.cpp.com.COMRuntime.newInstance(COMRuntime.java:262)
>       at org.bridj.cpp.com.COMRuntime.newInstance(COMRuntime.java:258)

Comment: а при чем тут JavaFx, если проблема в  Unexpected COM error code?

Comment: Гугление этой проблемы ни к чему не привели. Мне бы подсказку в какую сторону копать

Comment: Попробуйте в отдельном потоке вызывать `list = COMRuntime.newInstance(ITaskbarList3.class);` - JFX не любит, когда в его потоке вызывают что-то не относящееся к UI. Cмотрите тему связки (биндинги) - bindings и property - свойства в JavaFX.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!